# Multiprocessing vs gevent

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq, gevent, pyzmq

Currently I am using zeromq with pub-sub pattern, I have single worker to publish and many(8) subscriber (all will subscribe) to same pattern.

Now I tried multiprocessing to spawn subscribers  it works. I am missing few messages.

Why I am using multiprocessing is to handle each message as it arrives and process them, every second publisher publishes 10 - 100 messages.

In this case it is advised use `multiprocessing` or `gevent` ?

Answer (score 4):

Multiprocessing will clearly have much higher memory overhead but will utilize another core (and you don't have to worry about lack of pre-emption) so.. it depends on your needs.
It's likely that multiple processes using gevent will get you the highest throughput / lowest latency.

Comment: So you say that multiprocessing let us not worry about pre-emption please?

Answer (score 4):

### I am answering my own question

I choose multiprocessing over gevent

1. Server had 8 cores
2. Parallelism was needed
3. Choose ZMQ over multiprocessing queue or gevent queue.

Comment: So i guess the processes num are fixed, equal to the core num.

Comment: I am not sure about the points you mentioned under multiprocessing?